# ASP.NET and datetime-local set value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set a value of datetime-local to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm tt

This is where the date is coming from

```
item.PlannedStart = reader["PlannedStart"] == DBNull.Value ? null : ((DateTime?)reader["PlannedStart"]).Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt");
```

and here is my input field

```
<input type='datetime-local' name='PlannedStart' value='item.PlannedStart' class='form-control' />
```

However its not setting...when I use input type date

```
<input type='date' name='PlannedStart' value='item.PlannedStart' class='form-control' />
```

and set the date like to so

```
item.PlannedStart = reader["PlannedStart"] == DBNull.Value ? null : ((DateTime?)reader["PlannedStart"]).Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

it works, but when I set the time....what am I doing wrong?

If I actually check the value the date is there, but not displaying in the datetime-local text field.

Comment: `<input type="date"` only supports dates, not times. You could potentially use a separate [time field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) to input the time, or try a [datetime-local field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) to allow both at once. Browser support is a bit sketchy though

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to do is use datetime-local for both date and time, But when I try to set the value it does not work

Comment: Doesn't work how exactly? What browser are you testing with? Like I said, support for it is far from universal

Comment: P.s. from the docs I'd guess your time format is wrong. Try using a straightforward 24hr format instead am/pm formats

Comment: If I actually check the value the date is there (via inspecting the element), but not displaying in the datetime-local text field.

Comment: Hm. Did you try changing the time format as I mentioned?

Comment: How would I change the format to be 24 hour clock?

Comment: It's documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings but basically `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")` would achieve that

Comment: ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm") worked